# show information about connection state on status bar

Tags: ms-word, vsto, word-automation

VSTO document-level customization, using C#
I need to show permanent information about the connection state in a word document.
I had the idea to do it from the status bar but I don’t know how modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current object models for Word do not provide access to its Status Bar. The Word Status Bar provides a lot of information about the Word application, as well as controls for interacting with it and what it contains can be customized by the user. So there's no way provided for the Developer to access it, no should the Developer interfere with such an important part of the User UI.

EDIT: Since this is a VSTO document, it would be possible for you to display this information in the Actions Pane (task pane for the document). It would also be possible to display it in the Ribbon or possibly in the Title bar. The tricky part about this last is that the title bar will change/update as you'd be "sharing" it with the Word application. But the capability is built into the Word application, via its Window object. For example:

```
theDocument.Application.ActiveWindow.Caption = "custom text"
```

The text assiged to the Caption property will replace the document name and be positioned just before the text "Microsoft Word". If you want to retain the document name in the Title bar you'd need to query and append that to the string you assign to Caption.

Comment: while a document is open , the system maintains a connection check out some data servers.

The checks want to show to the user so that the user knows which server connection exists

Comment: Is this a VSTO add-in, VSTO document, VBA, something else...? That affects what kinds of UI you have access to.

Comment: i could use some emerging Ribbon or tape (such as safety warnings ) , to show me those values?

Comment: Unfortunately, the "message bar" used by safety warning is not accessible to the developer... If you had an application-level add-in it would be possible to create a Custom Task Pane (similar to an Actions Pane, but not linked to the document) that could be positioned (docked) above the document (instead of at the side). As I recall, the Actions Pane isn't quite as flexible in this respect...

Comment: I need also show innformation in a label, like 1 and 2 ......5 . changing like a count. Im trying with background work but doesn´t work